# Manually time out a httpurlconnection in java

Tags: java, timeout, settimeout, httpurlconnection

i have tried to timeout httpurlconnection in the following manner

```
URL urlConnect = new URL(url.toString());
HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) urlConnect.openConnection();
urlc.setConnectTimeout(1000*5);
urlc.setReadTimeout(1000*5);
urlc.connect();
```

but failed to connect, its taking the timeout assigned by apache tomcat of 2 minutes to timeout instead of 5 seconds gthat i have provided, in such cases how can in manually timeout the httpurlconnection

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following is what Java manual say for both connectTimeout and readTimeout:

connectTimeout

> Sets a specified timeout value, in milliseconds, to be used when
>   opening a communications link to the resource referenced by this
>   URLConnection. If the timeout expires before the connection can be
>   established, a java.net.SocketTimeoutException is raised. A timeout of
>   zero is interpreted as an infinite timeout.

readTimeout

> Sets the read timeout to a specified timeout, in milliseconds. A
>   non-zero value specifies the timeout when reading from Input stream
>   when a connection is established to a resource. If the timeout expires
>   before there is data available for read, a
>   java.net.SocketTimeoutException is raised. A timeout of zero is
>   interpreted as an infinite timeout.

So I think in your case, you manage to establish communications link in less than 5 seconds, and you did not read any input stream. Hence the behavior is correct (wait until Apache times out)